# Azure Insights dependencies metrics in the HTTP response headers

Tags: azure-application-insights, metrics

Azure Insights can capture and display all the application dependencies calls (db, 3rd party, blobs, queues etc) and it is available in the Azure Portal.

I am looking at the way how to include captured data in the HTTP response headers of HTTP calls to application with enabled Azure Insights tracing.

The use case, it when we run DotNetCore api and call a HTTP method we receive some stats about the number of dependency calls it performed.

Any direction from the community?

Looking at the documentation, but feature I am interested in is not available out-of-the-box.

Comment: So let me get this right: if you do a request to an App Insights enabled web app, you want that web app to store the number of dependency calls in the response header? But what if the dependency itself calls out to other services, should that be counted to?

Comment: It is probably much easier to create a kusto query showing the dependencies per request than to create this kind of logic. But it depends on what you want to do with the information

Comment: @PeterBons correct, I would like to see direct (non-recursive) number of dependencies calls.
The reason behind is I would like to run integration tests against this HTTP endpoints and add assertions about the number of dependencies calls performed internally by specific HTTP request.

Comment: There is the [TelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer). All telemetry will pass through it, including the request and all dependencies but it is stateless. Sou you need to keep track of the request and its dependencies possibly based on the operation id but you need to think of a way to persist it and store it in the request telemetry.

Comment: It might be easier to store the operationId in the response header and then use the Application Insights rest api or SKD to get the dependencies. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/overview

Comment: I think TelemetryInitializer would be useful for me. Let me try it and report back the results ...

Comment: Do let us know the developments made using TelemetryInitializer and whether it worked in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Peter Bons for suggestion. It works well, here is an example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace InsightsTelemetry;

public class ApiTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; }
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, int> OperationsMap = new();
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> ApiRequestsMap = new();

    public ApiTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        CountSqlDependencyCalls(item);
        Next.Process(item);
    }

    private static void CountSqlDependencyCalls(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // If this is not a SQL call, return
        if (item is not DependencyTelemetry {Type: "SQL"} dep) return;

        OperationsMap.TryGetValue(item.Context.Operation.Id, out var operationsCount);

        // If this is the first SQL call for this operation, add it to the map
        if (operationsCount == 0)
        {
            OperationsMap[item.Context.Operation.Id] = 0;
            ApiRequestsMap[MetricsMiddleware.RequestId] = item.Context.Operation.Id;
        }

        // Increment the count of SQL calls for this operation
        OperationsMap[item.Context.Operation.Id] = operationsCount + 1;

        // Print the SQL call to console
        Console.WriteLine(dep.Data + "\r\n");
    }
}
```

And middleware to append number of queries and total execution time for HTTP request.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace InsightsTelemetry
{
    internal class MetricsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public static string RequestId { get; private set; }

        public MetricsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            RequestId = context.Request.GetHashCode().ToString();
            var startDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            context.Response.OnStarting(_ =>
            {
                if (context.Response.HasStarted) return Task.FromResult(0);
                if (ApiTelemetryProcessor.ApiRequestsMap.TryGetValue(RequestId, out var operationId))
                {
                    var sqlQueriesCount = ApiTelemetryProcessor.OperationsMap[operationId].ToString();
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-SQL-Queries", sqlQueriesCount);
                }

                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Milliseconds-Elapsed",
                    Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.UtcNow - startDate).TotalMilliseconds).ToString());
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }, null!);

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register both in the AppStartup.cs.

```
app.UseMiddleware<MetricsMiddleware>();
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<ApiTelemetryProcessor>();
```